# Replace file extension inside a Particular Directory

Tags: regex, wordpress, replace, preg-replace, str-replace

I'm not a professional but I'm trying to use webp images with WordPress.

I have a plugin called Rj Webp Converter that converts images to webp format and then I'm using this function to replace the extension like jpg, jpeg and png to webp.

```
function callback($buffer) {
    if(!is_admin() && $GLOBALS['pagenow'] != 'wp-login.php') {
        $buffer = str_replace('.jpg','.webp',$buffer);
        $buffer = str_replace('.jpeg','.webp',$buffer);
        $buffer = str_replace('.png','.webp',$buffer); }
    return $buffer; }
function buffer_start() { ob_start("callback"); }
function buffer_end() { ob_end_flush(); }
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'buffer_start');
add_action('shutdown', 'buffer_end');
```

But there's one problem.
The above code replaces every image file.
I want to replace the files which are only inside the wp-content/uploads/... directory.

Any help is appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0):

***This Should Work.***

**REGEX**

```
<?php
$re = '/(.*(?<=\.)(?:jpg|jpeg|png)(?=$))/m';
$str = 'test.jpg
testing.png
test.jpeg';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);

// Print the entire match result
print_r($matches);
?>
```

**PHP** *You should replace $filename to $matches* using foreach.

```
function replace_extension($filename, $new_extension) {
    $info = pathinfo($filename);
    return $info['filename'] . '.' . $new_extension;
}
```